# How can i show a pop-up in client side from server side in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a function that does Excel import, while this function is working i want to show a pop-up to client and he decides to continue the function work or stop it. First call of the function is jQuery Call so how can i manage the state of my done work in the function. this is implemented in MVC project.

Comment: if you need two-way real-time communication between client and server (without having to refresh the page) then you should look into SignalR

Comment: @ADyson My situation is that while i'm in server side i want to show a pop-up to user and he choose if he wanna keep changes or not. If he want to keep changes i have to return to controller to continue my work so i started the first call to controller with Ajax and the issue is that i need to keep the same state and continue

Comment: " while i'm in server side i want to show a pop-up to user" ...that makes no sense in a web context. if you want to show something to the user then you have to end the request and send a response from the server back to the browser. That's how HTTP works. So basically to do what you're suggesting you actually just need two action methods in your MVC - one to return the proposed changes and let the user validate, and another to finalise them if user confirms. (Or it could be the same action method but sending a different parameter value). And the server would need to maintain state in between.

Comment: So yes it makes sense to do this via AJAX rather than repeated postbacks. Maybe you need to the server to store something in the Session or in a temporary table in the database, so it can remember what is happening in between the first request and the confirmation (or cancellation, I guess).

Comment: @ADyson exactly , i'll work with Ajax call but my problem is how to maintain state

Comment: You do it using one of the things I mentioned above - the Session, a database, even a text file could be used in theory. Anything which can be preserved between requests. Save everything that you'll need to know next time a request from the same user comes in. When it does, you can load that data into a variable again and use it.